# sqlite3 Module not found error and Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, sqlite, pip, virtualenv

Have been trying to run my python program on my hosted server. I tried doing it with an virtualenv mentioned over here https://www.godaddy.com/garage/how-to-install-and-configure-python-on-a-hosted-server/ I am using PUTTY to run the program but its showing this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

for which I used `pip install pysqlite` but then I am getting these  error

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2r8gt1bv/pysqlite/

Comment: what version of pip are you on?

Comment: Have you got more than one version of python installed?

Comment: i am using Godaddy's server. so Python2 was Pre-install in that server. i am using virtual environment and running my code over there and have install python 3.6.5 on virtual environment.